# What does a 10MW wind turbine mean?

Tags: power, generator, energy

So if a wind turbine has a capacity of 10MW, what does that exactly mean? does it produce 10MW every hour, or is it the peak power it can generate at any time?

the following question is how to know how much MWh does it produce in a certain time-frame (lets say 24hrs)?

Comment: Peak generation at some given wind speed. E=P*t.

Comment: watts have no time factor, it's just volts times amps, so if constant, in 24h you expect 240Mwh.

Comment: @dandavis as long as the wind blows...

Comment: That beast produces 10,000,000 joules a second, which is the energy output of 10 sticks of dynamite. It can kill you.

Comment: This kind of rating is called *nominal*; the exact meaning depends on who wrote it and why, but usually it indicates some kind of average or expected power output under either average or good conditions. You don't get 10MW all the time, because it depends on the wind conditions. (By contrast a 10MW coal plant can be expected to produce 10MW all day every day)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 10 MW wind turbine can be expected to output 10 MW (power) at the rated wind speed. If the wind remained at that speed for one hour then the output would be 10 MWh (energy). Over 24 hours that would total 240 MWh. At, say, 5 c/kWh that would be worth €12k.

I can't find a figure but I suspect that, on average, the output will be about one third of the rated output due to calm days, etc.

Have a look at the *Wind* chapter of David McKay's excellent [Sustainable Energy Without the Hot Air](https://www.withouthotair.com/c4/page_32.shtml) which is available in book form or free PDF or HTML form. It provides figures relevant to Britain but the principles apply anywhere.

Comment: the capacity rating is a peak output before a safety shutdown, the output depends on two unknowns: the efficiency of the turbine (relates mainly to the magnets and blade size) and the location's climate: high avg wind speed and low anomaly (yielding times when winds are to high/low to be usable). There's [map generators for the US](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/societal-impacts/wind/), perhaps other nations offer the same thing?